# how to send file's binary to params and save it in DB with paperclip_database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Sorry for maybe newbie question.
I want to use a paperclip and paperclip_database gems to attach and save files in my database.
But I stuck on sending file's data from views to controller.
I've done all from [this](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/3.5.3), and [this](http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/2/19/database-storage-for-paperclip) resources. As the result I have next models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certificates, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :certificates, :allow_destroy => true
end
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessor :image
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :storage => :database,
                    :database_table => 'image_files',
                    :cascade_deletion => true
end
```

in a controller

```
Users_controller
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.certificates.build
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  end
end
```

and my view form is:

```
<%= form_tag @user, method: :put, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|%>
  <%= fields_for each_event_entry.certificates.first do |c| %>
    <tr>
      <th>Certificate</th>
      <td>
        <%= c.file_field :image %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But when I attach a file and try to submit, I've only got a file name in params:

```
{
 "user" => {"some"=>"params"}
 "certificate"=>{"image"=>"IMG_1642.JPG"}
 }
```

And certificate is saved whithout attached file.
Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out the problem.

It appears to be that the "form_tag" form doesn't need an :html attribute, so the html form should look like:

```
<%= form_tag @user, :multipart => true do |f| %>
```

In my case, there is no necessity of method: as well.

Hope this will help someone.